# ZenCart to Magento import

Tags: magento, import, migration, database-migration, zen-cart

I am looking to migrate ZenCart "customers" to an existing Magento website. I tried two extensions from MagentoConnect; however it doesn't works.

[osCommerce Migration Tool](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/oscommerce-migration-tool.html) [osCommerce Import](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/oscommerce-categories-products-customers-orders-migration-tool.html)

There are premium 3rd party migration services available in market, however I would like to do this my own. Please help me out by providing some steps to this through code.

Currently the zen cart DB is having prefix "zen_". Will this be causing inconvenience ? please point me out a starting point on this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have sorted this my own. What surprised me is, there are no valid doc on how to import customers from ZenCart/OsCommerce to Magento any where around web unless some forum with premium Magento extensions. Hence I am posting my solution here which would be a help for any one who is looking for this same solution.

**Fetching ZenCart customer details**

Obviously ZenCart uses MySQL DB. Get into MySQL prompt and look into the *customers* table. Use the below command respectively.

```
use ZenCart_DB
mysql> select * from customers\G
```

You can see the details of your ZenCart customers there. Sample output will be like this per customer.

```
customers_id: 1298
        customers_gender: m
     customers_firstname: firstname
      customers_lastname: Lastname
           customers_dob: 
 customers_email_address: customer@email.com
          customers_nick: 
customers_default_address_id: 
     customers_telephone: 12345678
           customers_fax: 
      customers_password: dd2df54a57a4d35ffd2985b3584f0831:2c
    customers_newsletter: 0
 customers_group_pricing: 0
  customers_email_format: TEXT
 customers_authorization: 0
      customers_referral: 
customers_paypal_payerid: 
     customers_paypal_ec: 0
           COWOA_account: 0
```

This is a sample and we have to take all these customer details to a unix file.

```
select * from customers into outfile 'customer.txt'\G
```

Now come out of MySQL prompt. To create a Magento user, we only need *firstname,lastname,email and password.* These four details are mandatory. Hence grep those details from the *customer.txt* file.

The location of customer.txt file will be */var/lib/mysql/ZenCart_DB/customer.txt*

Grep the required customer details to different individual files which will help us to put them into **for** loop later.

```
awk {'print $3,$4,$7,$10'} customer.txt > details.txt
awk {'print$1'} details.txt > zen_firstname
awk {'print$2'} details.txt > zen_secondname
awk {'print$3'} details.txt > zen_email
awk {'print$4'} details.txt > zen_password
```

**Creating a Magento user**

No we have collected all the details. Now to create a test Magento user from backend, we have to run 5 MySQL queries in magento database. They are,

```
INSERT INTO customer_entity ( entity_id, entity_type_id, attribute_set_id, website_id, email, group_id, increment_id, store_id, created_at, updated_at, is_active, disable_auto_group_change) VALUES ( 1, 1, 0, 1, $email, 1, NULL, 4, 2014-11-24 11:50:33, 2014-11-24 12:05:53, 1, 0)

INSERT INTO customer_entity_varchar (value_id, entity_type_id, attribute_id, entity_id, value) VALUES (1, 1, 5, 1, $firstname);

INSERT INTO customer_entity_varchar (value_id, entity_type_id, attribute_id, entity_id, value) VALUES (2, 1, 7, 1, '$lastname' );

INSERT INTO customer_entity_varchar (value_id, entity_type_id, attribute_id, entity_id, value) VALUES (3, 1, 12, 1, '$password' );

INSERT INTO customer_entity_varchar (value_id, entity_type_id, attribute_id, entity_id, value) VALUES (5, 1, 3, 1, 'English' );
```

If you have too many customers to add, then better put them in for loop. This is optional for each person. we can create **for** loop in bash or similar in Perl or what ever language you are good at.

Few things to note,

- entity_id value is important and it should be the same in all the 5 queries. It determines the customer's ID number.
- value_id is like serial number to the rows in table customer_entity_varchar. Follow the sequence as it is.
- attribute_id should be kept as it is in the sequence 5,7,12,3 as it represents customers firstname, lastname, password, language respectively.

That's all I think. Thanks. :)